Evaluating $\frac1{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{l=1}^m\sin(rA_k)\sin(rA_l)\cos(rA_k-rA_l)$ for natural $r\leq m$, and $A_k=\frac{2k-1}{2m}\pi$
IMO 1969 Longlist problem 38:

Let $r$ and $m$ ($r \leq m$) be natural numbers and $A_k = \frac{2k-1}{2m}\pi$.
Evaluate
$$\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=1}^{m}\sin(rA_k)\sin(rA_l)\cos(rA_k - rA_l)$$

My solution to the problem progresses as follows
$$\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=1}^{m}\sin(rA_k)\sin(rA_l)\cos(rA_k - rA_l)$$
$$\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=1}^{m}\frac{\cos(rA_k - rA_l) - \cos(rA_k + rA_l)}{2}\times\cos(rA_k - rA_l)$$
$$\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=1}^{m}\frac{\cos^2(rA_k - rA_l) - \cos(rA_k + rA_l)\cos(rA_k - rA_l)}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=1}^{m}\frac{\cos^2(rA_k - rA_l) - \cos^2(rA_k + rA_l) - \cos^2(rA_k - rA_l) + 1}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=1}^{m}\frac{\sin^2(rA_k + rA_l)}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=1}^{m}\frac{1-\cos(2rA_k + 2rA_l)}{4}$$
$$\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Biggl(\frac{m}{4} - \frac{1}{4}\Bigr(\cos(2rA_k + 2rA_1) + \cos(2rA_k + 2rA_2) + \cdots + \cos(2rA_k + 2rA_m)\Bigl)\Biggr)$$
$$\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Biggl(\frac{m}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\Bigr(\cos(\frac{r\pi(2k-1)}{m} + \frac{r\pi}{m}) + \cos(\frac{r\pi(2k-1)}{m} + \frac{3r\pi}{m}) + \cdots + \cos(\frac{r\pi(2k-1)}{m} + \frac{(2l-1)\pi r}{m})\Bigl)\Biggr)$$
$$\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\Biggl(\frac{m}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{\sin(\pi r)}{\sin(\pi r/m)}\cos\Bigl(\pi r(\frac{2k + m - 1}{m})\Bigr)\Biggr)$$
After this it is quite easy to say that another arithmetic progression is forming in cosine which can also be simplified but i seem to not get a integer solution to the problem and the solution is neither available in the IMO compendium nor did i find any solution on the internet could someone please check if i have done any mistakes or is the answer not an integer if so, i would be highly grateful.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

$$\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=1}^{m}\sin(rA_k)\sin(rA_l)\cos(rA_k - rA_l)=\begin{cases}
1, & r=m \
\frac{1}{4}, & r<m
\end{cases}$$

@gpmath, does my solution when proceeded with yield the same answer?

unfortunately no.

@gpmath could you point out where my mistake is?

The double sum evaluates to
$$\frac{m^2+\sin ^2(\pi  r) \csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi  r}{m}\right)-m \sin (2 \pi  r) \csc \left(\frac{\pi  r}{m}\right)}{4 m^2}$$
Don't know what you did wrong.

@gpmath could you post your solution because my final answer is pretty close to what you evaluated

@gpmath my answer comes out to be the following
$$\frac{m^2 - sin^2(\pi r)\csc^2((\pi r)/m)\cos(2\pi r)}{4m^2}$$

I guess an error in your calculations happened when you replaced $- \cos(rA_k + rA_l)\cos(rA_k - rA_l)$ by $- \cos^2(rA_k + rA_l) - \cos^2(rA_k - rA_l) + 1$.

@koiboi if you feel satisfied by any of the answers you can consider accepting.

Let $S$ be the required sum. Then
$$m^2S=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=1}^{m}\sin rA_k \sin rA_l \cos(rA_k - rA_l)=$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=1}^{m}\sin rA_k \sin rA_l (\cos rA_k \cos rA_l +
\sin rA_k \sin rA_l)=$$
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m} \sin rA_k \cos rA_k \right)\left(\sum_{l=1}^{m} \sin rA_l \cos rA_l \right)+$$ $$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m} \sin^2 rA_k \right)\left(\sum_{l=1}^{m} \sin^2 rA_l \right).$$ The latter sum is equal to $S_1^2+S_2^2,$
where $$S_1=\sum_{k=1}^{m} \sin rA_k \cos rA_k=\frac 12\sum_{k=1}^{m} \sin 2rA_k$$ and $$S_2=\sum_{k=1}^{m} \sin^2 rA_k=\frac 12\sum_{k=1}^{m} 1-\cos 2rA_k.$$
For each natural $k\le m$ let $$Z_k=(\sin 2rA_k,\cos 2rA_k)=\left(\sin\frac{(2k-1)r\pi}m,\cos\frac{(2k-1)r\pi}m\right)$$ be a point of the unit circle centered at the origin $(0,0)$.
When $r=m$ then $Z_k=(\sin\pi,\cos\pi)=(0,-1)$ for each natural $k\le m$, so $S_1=0$,  $S_2=m$, and $S=1$.
Suppose now that $r<m$. Then for each natural $k<m$ the point $Z_{k+1}$ is the point $Z_k$ rotated counterclockwise around the origin by the angle $\alpha=\frac{2r\pi}m\in (0,2\pi)$. Since $m\alpha=2r\pi$, this rotation maps the set $\{Z_1,Z_2,\dots,Z_m\}$ into itself. Therefore this rotation preserves its sum $$X=\sum_{k=1}^{m} Z_k=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m} \sin 2rA_k,\sum_{k=1}^{m} \cos 2rA_k\right).$$
Since $\alpha\in (0,2\pi)$, we have $X=0$, so $S_1=0$,  $S_2=\frac m2$, and $S=\frac 14$.

@koiboi I completed my answer.


Lemma: $$\sum_{n=1}^{m} \sin(a + nd) = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{md}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{2a + md + d}2\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{d}2\right)}$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^{m} \cos(a + nd) = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{md}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{2a + md + d}2\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{d}2\right)}$$

Proof: Consider the LHS of both equations scaled by a multiplication of $\sin\left(\frac{d}2\right)$. Upon using the identities for $\sin(a)\sin(b)$ and $\sin(a)\cos(b)$ for the first and second qualities respectively one finds that the sums telescope and yield the lemma.
To your problem, defining $A_k = \frac{2k-1}{2m}\pi$, one has
$$\begin{align}m^2S&:= \sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{l=1}^m \sin(rA_k)\sin(rA_l) \cos(rA_k - rA_l) \\ m^2S &= \sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{l=1}^m \sin(rA_k)\sin(rA_l)\left(\cos(rA_k)\cos(rA_l) + \sin(rA_k)\sin(rA_l)\right)  \tag{1.1}\\ m^2S &= \sum_{k=1}^m \sin(rA_k)\cos(rA_k)\sum_{l=1}^m \sin(rA_l)\cos(rA_l) + \sum_{k=1}^m \sin^2(rA_k) \sum_{l=1}^m \sin^2(rA_l) \tag{1.2}\\ m^2S &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^m \sin(rA_k)\cos(rA_k)\right)^2 + \left(\sum_{k=1}^m \sin^2(rA_k)\right)^2 \tag{1.3} \\ m^2S &= \frac14\left(\sum_{k=1}^m 2\sin(rA_k)\cos(rA_k)\right)^2 + \frac14\left(\sum_{k=1}^m 2\sin^2(rA_k)\right)^2 \iff \\
4m^2S &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^m \sin(2rA_k)\right)^2 + \left(\sum_{k=1}^m 1-\cos(2rA_k)\right)^2 \tag{1.4} \\
4m^2S &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^m \sin\left(\frac{r}{m}(2k-1)\pi\right)\right)^2 + \left(m - \sum_{k=1}^m \cos\left(\frac{r}{m}(2k-1)\pi\right)\right)^2 \tag{1.5}\\
4m^2S &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^m \sin\left(\frac{2r\pi}{m}k - \frac{r\pi}{m}\right)\right)^2 + \left(m - \sum_{k=1}^m \cos\left(\frac{2r\pi}{m}k - \frac{r\pi}{m}\right)\right)^2 \\
4m^2S &= \csc^2\left(\frac{r\pi}{m}\right)\cdot \sin^4\left(r\pi\right) + \left(m - \sin(r\pi)\cos(r\pi)\csc\left(\frac{r\pi}{m}\right)\right)^2 \tag{1.6} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (\not\exists p\in\mathbb Z : r=mp)\\
S &= \frac{m^2 + \csc^2\left(\frac{r\pi}{m}\right)\sin^2(r\pi) - m\sin(2r\pi)\csc\left(\frac{r\pi}{m}\right)}{4m^2} \tag{1.7}
\end{align}$$
But if $\exists p \in \mathbb Z: r=mp$ then at $(1.5)$ the lemma can not be applied; instead $$\begin{align} 4m^2S &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^m \color{green}{\sin(p(2k-1)\pi)}\right)^2 + \left(m - \sum_{k=1}^m \color{pink}{\cos(p(2k-1)\pi)}\right)^2 \\ 4m^2S &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^m \color{green}{0}\right)^2 + \left(m - \sum_{k=1}^m \color{pink}{\pm 1}\right)^2 \tag{1.8}\\ 4m^2S &= \begin{cases}0 & p\text{ is even} \\ 4m^2 & p\text{ is odd}\end{cases}\end{align}$$
Thus, we can combine all three results into one "short" form:
$$\boxed{S = \begin{cases}0 & \frac{r}{m} \text{ is even} \\ \\ 1 &\frac{r}{m}\text{ is odd} \\ \\ \frac{m^2 + \csc^2\left(\frac{r\pi}{m}\right)\sin^2(r\pi) - m\sin(2r\pi)\csc\left(\frac{r\pi}{m}\right)}{4m^2} & \frac{r}{m} \notin \mathbb Z\end{cases}}$$
This is the most general closed-form of this summation. When $0<r<m$ with $r, m \in \mathbb Z$ we have that the last case applies from the closed form of $S$ and since $\sin(r\pi) = 0$, all but one of the terms vanish and we are left with $S= \frac14$. When $r=m$ we have that the second case applies of the closed form of $S$ and we get $S=1$.
Explanations:
$(1.1)$ follows from the compound $\cos$ identity.
$(1.2)$ and $(1.3)$ follow from distributivity of addition over multiplication.
$(1.4)$ follows via the identity $2\sin(a)\cos(a) = \sin(2a)$ and $\sin^2(a) = 1-\cos(2a)$.
$(1.6)$ follows from applying aforesaid lemma. The restraint comes from that $\csc$ must be defined for this formula to hold. The other case is also handled.
$(1.7)$ using $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$, regrouping, and using $\sin^2(r\pi) = \sin^4(r\pi) + \sin^2(r\pi)\cos^2(r\pi)$.
$(1.8)$ for any integer $n$, $\sin(nx) = 0$; if $n$ is odd then $\cos(nx) = -1$ and if $n$ is even then $\cos(nx) = 1$.

May the downvoter explain the reason for the downvote?

I'm going to first point out a mistake in your solution, and then write my solution.
I think there is a mistake in the step from
$$\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=1}^{m}\frac{\cos^2(rA_k - rA_l) - \cos(rA_k + rA_l)\cos(rA_k - rA_l)}{2}\tag1$$
to
$$\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=1}^{m}\frac{\cos^2(rA_k - rA_l) - \cos^2(rA_k + rA_l) - \cos^2(rA_k - rA_l) + 1}{2}\tag2$$
For $r=m=2$ for example, we have $(1)=1$ while $(2)=0$.

In the following, I'm going to write my solution.
We have, as written in Alex Ravsky's answer,
$$\begin{align}&\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=1}^{m}\sin(rA_k)\sin(rA_l)\cos(rA_k-rA_l)
\\\\&=\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{l=1}^{m}\sin(rA_k)\sin(rA_l)\bigg(\cos(rA_k)\cos(rA_l)+\sin(rA_k)\sin(rA_l)\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sin(rA_k)\cos(rA_k)\sum_{l=1}^{m}\sin(rA_l)\cos(rA_l)+\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sin^2(rA_k)\sum_{l=1}^{m}\sin^2(rA_l)
\\\\&=\frac{1}{m^2}A^2+\frac{1}{m^2}B^2\end{align}$$
where
$$A=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sin(rA_k)\cos(rA_k),B=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sin^2(rA_k)$$
For $r=m$, we have $A=0$ and $B=m$.
For $r\lt m$, using this, we have
$$\begin{align}A&=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sin(rA_k)\cos(rA_k)
\\\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac 12\sin(2rA_k)
\\\\&=\frac 12\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sin\bigg(-\frac{r\pi}{m}+k\cdot\frac{2r\pi}{m}\bigg)
\\\\&=-\frac 12\sin\bigg(-\frac{r\pi}{m}\bigg)+\frac 12\sum_{k=\color{red}0}^{m}\sin\bigg(-\frac{r\pi}{m}+k\cdot\frac{2r\pi}{m}\bigg)
\\\\&=-\frac 12\sin\bigg(-\frac{r\pi}{m}\bigg)+\frac 12\sin\bigg(-\frac{r\pi}{m}\bigg)
\\\\&=0\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}B&=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sin^2(rA_k)
\\\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1-\cos(2rA_k)}{2}
\\\\&=\frac m2-\frac 12\sum_{k=1}^{m}\cos\bigg(-\frac{r\pi}{m}+k\cdot\frac{2r\pi}{m}\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac m2+\frac 12\cos\bigg(-\frac{r\pi}{m}\bigg)-\frac 12\sum_{k=\color{red}0}^{m}\cos\bigg(-\frac{r\pi}{m}+k\cdot\frac{2r\pi}{m}\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac m2+\frac 12\cos\bigg(-\frac{r\pi}{m}\bigg)-\frac 12\cos\bigg(-\frac{r\pi}{m}\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac m2\end{align}$$
Therefore, the answer is $$\color{red}{\begin{cases}\dfrac 14&\text{if $r\lt m$}\\1&\text{if $r=m$}\end{cases}}$$

To the downvoter, can you explain why you downvoted my answer so that I can improve my answer?

How unfortunate that all three answers were downvoted without explanation. The bounty too was left un-rewarded.
